# How do I maintain text layout when using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have the following text file:

1. This is the first line of the text file.
2. This is the second line,
3. and here goes the third.

When using

```
echo file_get_contents($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/file.txt");
```

The output is

> This is the first line of the text
>   file. This is the second line, and
>   here goes the third.

How do I prevent the layout from changing?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML, new line characters (`\n` or `\r\n`) don't cause actual line breaks to appear in the rendered page. Here are two possible solutions:

1. Use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to convert newlines to `<BR>` tags. This will work for some layouts, but not for ASCII art or others that rely on multiple spaces (which are reduced to one in HTML).

   ```
   echo nl2br(file_get_contents(...));
   ```
2. Wrap the result in `<pre>` tags. This will keep all layout, but can look a bit ugly. You can style `<pre>` tags with CSS to make them prettier, if you'd prefer.

   ```
   echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents(...) . '</pre>';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are gonna use PHP, it must be done in 2 parts:

1. Write your page in pure HTML. Make it work as desired. Ask HTML questions if any.
2. Write a PHP script which produce the the same text.

An HTML tag that could help you is `<pre>`

Another way to tell to browser that here hoes plain text is to send appropriate HTTP header
So, it this text is the only text being displayed on this page,

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/file.txt");
```

Comment: Good to know about the header, though I have muliple text files as sources. :-)